# control.BeginInvoke() Vs Dispatcher Vs SynchronizationContext Vs .. - RELIABILITY

Tags: c#, delegates

Invoking a UI thread from a worker thread is discussed lot of times and we know why to use BeginInvoke() instead of Invoke(). I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270514/control-begininvoke-fails-to-call-the-delegate,) and after doing some research I found out that there are at least three different ways (internally they might be same) to invoke (asynchronously) something on UI thread.

1. `Control.BeginInvoke()`
2. Using `SynchronizatoinContext` Class
3. Using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(priority.. )`

Can anyone tell me which is a RELIABLE way to asynchronously call a method to be executed on UI thread. Any experience ? I see Dispatcher.BeginInvoke has priority component to it, does it make it more reliable ?

**Context**:
we are using `someControl.BeginInvoke()` but noticed that sometimes (unfortunately only in the end user production environment) the delegate passed to `BeginInvoke is` never executed which makes me believe that the post message which it creates is getting lost. We want a reliable way to communicate back to the UI thread. `control.Invoke()` sometimes hang the UI so we don't want to go there either.

Comment: Do not confuse WinForms with WPF.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem... by any chance did you manage to correct the problem?

Comment: same here, any update?

Answer (score 0):

They all operate as they should, if you call `BeginInvoke` and sometimes nothing happens, there's some problem in the environment or calling code, probably - it's not that `BeginInvoke` is unreliable.  Well - there could be a bug, but it's far less likely.

Perhaps you could give more context and we can help diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a similar scenario in our code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270514/control-begininvoke-fails-to-call-the-delegate

Comment: Hi karephul, that's interesting but doesn't help out much in this case since they didn't find an answer either.  What is your basic setup in terms of threads, processes, locks, etc?

Comment: Oh... is that the same problem? Just reposted here ?

Comment: There is a flaw in your logic in the other example.  If there is an exception on the UI thread, `executing` stays as `true` and the method will not be called anymore.  Perhaps that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

SynchronizationContext is more abstract and adaptable in more case. It is a wrapper of specific implementation.
MSDN says "Providers of synchronization models can extend this class and provide their own implementations for these methods".

Comment: SynchronizationContext is perferred here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/1218c86e-fa9b-45a6-93b0-5e27616a6c21

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with lambda functions and BeginInvoke. I had code like this that resulted in all sorts of weird behavior.

```
MyThing thing;
while( GetThing(ref thing)) {
    control.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => control.Text = thing.ToString()));
}
```

The problem is that `thing` is not evaluated when you create the lambda function. It is evaluated when the lamdba function gets executed. But it is bound to a variable that is changing at the same time in the producer thread.

You can fix this problem by declaring a local variable copy of `thing`

```
MyThing thing;
while( GetThing(ref thing)) {
  MyThing thing_x = thing;
  control.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => control.Text = thing_x.ToString()));
}
```

Or you can put the BeginInvoke ugliness in a wrapper

```
MyThing thing;
while( GetThing(ref thing)) {
  SetText(thing);
}

void SetText(MyThing thing)
  control.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => control.Text = thing.ToString()));
}
```