# Reasons that Control.BeginInvoke would not execute a delegate?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, begininvoke

### Overview

Are there explanations for Control.BeginInvoke() to not execute a delegate that it is passed?

### Code Sample

We have adopted the following pattern in our Winforms applications to safely execute UI releated work on the UI thread:

```
private Control hiddenControl = new Control();

private void uiMethod()
{
  MethodInvoker uiDelegate = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  {
    Logging.writeLine("Start of uiDelegate");
    //ui releated operations
    childDialog = new ChildDialog();
    childDialow.show();
    Logging.writeLine("End of uiDelegate");
  });

  if (hiddenControl.InvokeRequired)
  {
    Logging.writeLine("Start of InvokeRequired block");
    hiddenControl.BeginInvoke(uiDelegate);
    Logging.writeLine("End of InvokeRequired block");
  }
  else
  {
    uiDelegate();
  }
}
```

Here, we create a control "hiddenControl" explicitly for the purpose of running delegates on the UI Thread.  We never call endInvoke because it's apparently [not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532722/is-endinvoke-optional-sort-of-optional-or-definitely-not-optional) for Control.BeginInvoke and we never need to return a value because our methods just manipulate UI, anyway.

While extremely verbose, this pattern seems to be a [relatively](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke) [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke) [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532722/is-endinvoke-optional-sort-of-optional-or-definitely-not-optional) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714666/is-it-appropriate-to-extend-control-to-provide-consistently-safe-invoke-begininv).  There is, however, some [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270514/control-begininvoke-fails-to-call-the-delegate) that even this pattern may not work well in all situations.

### Observations

I'm not ruling out an application error and blaming WinForms.  After all, [select probably isn't broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).  I am however at a loss to explain why a delegate may seemingly not run at all.

In our case, we sometimes observe that the "Start of uiDelegate" log message never executes in certain threading scenarios, even though the "Start of InvokeReqiured block" and "End of InvokeRequired block" execute successfully.

It's been very hard to replicate this behavior because our application is delivered as a DLL; our customers run it in their own applications.  Therefore, we can not make any guarantees how or in which thread these methods may be called.

We ruled out UI thread starvation because it is observed that the UI does not lock down.  Presumably, if the UI is being updated, then the message pump is operational and available for pulling messages from the message queue and executing their delegates.

### Summary

Given this information, is there anything that we can try to make these calls more bullet-proof?  As previously mentioned, we have relatively little control over other threads in a given application, and do not control which context these methods are invoked.

What else can affect how delegates successfully passed to Control.BeginInvoke() execute or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) `InvokeRequired` can return `false` even in cases where `InvokeRequired` should be `true` - namely in the case that you access `InvokeRequired` before the `Handle` of that control/form (or a parent of it) has been created.

Basically your check is incomplete which leads to the result you see.

You need to check [`IsHandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated.aspx) - if that is `false` then you are in trouble because an `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` would be necessary BUT won't work robustly since `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` check which thread created `Handle` to do their magic...

Only if `IsHandleCreated` is `true` you act based on what `InvokeRequired` returns - something along the lines of:

```
if (control.IsHandleCreated)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
else 
{ 
    // in this case InvokeRequired might lie - you need to make sure that this never happens! 
    throw new Exception ( "Somehow Handle has not yet been created on the UI thread!" );
}
```

**Thus the following is important to avoid this problem**

Always make sure that the `Handle` is already created BEFORE the first access on a thread other than the UI thread.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) you just need to reference `control.Handle` in the UI thread to force it being created - in your code this must happen BEFORE the very first time you access that control/form from any thread that is not the UI thread.

For other possibilities see the answer from @JaredPar .

Comment: Great, I believe that the Control.Handle is the issue.  We were specifically calling control.Handle in the constructor, but if the c'tor isn't called on the main thread, the control is bound to a non-ui-thread and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx, " isolating the control on a thread without a message pump and making the application unstable."

Comment: Hi, did this handle check resolve all your problems? we have moved over to  using Synchronization to make these calls but still see a few calls missed by UI or few threads waiting forever for UI to respond (Send calls). Would appreciate your reply, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of reasons for which a `BeginInvoke` call can fail.

1. The control and all of it's parents don't have an internal handle created.  This would cause an exception at the call site
2. The control posted the delegate but was destroyed before it was actually run on the UI thread
3. The UI thread stops pumping messages (usually thread ends)

It sounds like it's very possible that #2 is causing your grief here.  I've had this problem a couple of times developing winform applications.  It caused me enough grief that I switched from `Control.BeginInvoke` to `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post`.  The `SynchronizationContext.Current` instance will live for the life time of the UI thread in a WinForms app and IMHO is a bit more reliable than invoking off of a specific `Control`

Comment: Thanks.  I'd like to try the SynchronizationContext.Current pattern, but how do I get a reference to it if I can't guarantee that I'm on the main UI Thread?  SynchronizationContext.Current will return null if not on the main thread.  Can I discover that context in a reliable way, or will I need to expose a method to pass the context in?

Comment: @16bytes usually I just pass it along to the start of any background operation that i kick off.  It can be tedious at times but it's the only reliable way to accomplish it.

Comment: we also tried with Synchronization.Current Send/Post methods, but there are times when UI thread doesn't pick these calls, even though it's running fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably throwing an exception in your first Logging call. I would suggest taking a look at the TPL, though (if you are using .Net 4.0). Tasks can make your code much more readable, and you can do something like the following

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{...Do Some stuff not on the UI thread...});
Task continuationTask = t.ContinueWith((previousTask)=>{...Do your UI stuff now 
         (let the Task Scheduler deal with jumping back on the UI thread...},
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Then, you can also easily check if any of the tasks have exceptions via continuationTask.Exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind, but unfortunately we can't move to 4.0 yet.